# BluetoothGatt.discoverservices doesn't discover services

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Application that need to connect to BLE devices, everything was going okay, i was able to connect to the BLE device and extract data from it successfully, until the last day, I couldn't connect to any of BLE device, I've discovered that the `BluetoothGatt` class has 58 errors, the main error is the it cannot solve the symbol `IBluetoothGatt` and this lead to the other errors and the discoverservices method is also colored in red, therefor the 
 `mBluetoothGatt.discoverservices` doesn't discover services and now i can't connect to any BLE device, did anyone else's faced this problem. I really appreciate any help because i have to finish this project by the end of this month and due to this problem i can't make any progress in this project

```
    package android.bluetooth;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.ParcelUuid;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Public API for the Bluetooth GATT Profile.
 *
 * <p>This class provides Bluetooth GATT functionality to enable communication
 * with Bluetooth Smart or Smart Ready devices.
 *
 * <p>To connect to a remote peripheral device, create a {@link BluetoothGattCallback}
 * and call {@link BluetoothDevice#connectGatt} to get a instance of this class.
 * GATT capable devices can be discovered using the Bluetooth device discovery or BLE
 * scan process.
 */
public final class BluetoothGatt implements BluetoothProfile {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothGatt";
    private static final boolean DBG = true;
    private static final boolean VDBG = false;

    private IBluetoothGatt mService;
```

The`mBluetoothGatt.discoverservices` doesn't work because it is also colored in red

Comment: BluetoothGatt is not a class in your application. It's a compiled class already on your phone. If you anyway open it in Android studio it might show some errors but you shall ignore those. Your problem cause is somewhere else.

Comment: can you attach the log?

Comment: Thanks for answering me I really appreciate it, I've tried an old version of the project before the added part, it gave me the same problem, I've checked the history it showed me 2 identical codes of BluetoothGatt class, the first one is free of errors, and the identical one on the other side is filled with errors Markus Kauppinen

Comment: payam, Thanks for answering me i really appreciate it, sorry i'm new to stackoverflow, what do you mean by log?

Comment: watch this: https://support.spryfox.com/hc/en-us/articles/218506088-How-do-I-get-a-Log-File-using-Android-Studio-

Comment: thanks a lot payam, I've solved the problem, the application used to automatically turn on the Bluetooth on my smartphone, but suddenly sopped doing that,when I've noticed that the Bluetooth symbol doesn't appear ,I've turned it on and the device connected, thank you for your help